# WPF MouseLeftButtonDown makes FlowDocument unable to select text

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I add a function that adds text to `FlowDocument` when the mouse clicks.
There is no `Click` event in `FlowDocument`, so I listen to `FlowDocument.MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` and check whether the mouse moves between down and up. When I click the mouse left button, the text successfully adds. However, I can't select any text in the `FlowDocument`.

I tried `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`. The behavior is the same. Isn't there a `PostMouseLeftButtonDown`?

My Code:

```
        Point mouseDownPoint;
        private void doc_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDownPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(doc);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void doc_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var mouseUpPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(doc);
            if ((mouseUpPoint - mouseDownPoint).Length < 8) /* add text */;
        }
```

Comment: That's what e.Handled = true does.  Wanting a mousedown to do two things is not a good idea.  Maybe a right-click or a button, it isn't very obvious how this is useful.

Comment: @HansPassant Internal select text behavior only invokes when a user drags mouse. Mouse down and up without moving in a `FlowDocument` will do nothing. This is not one operation to do two things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Listen to `FlowDocument.MouseLeftButtonDown` and do not use `e.Handled=true` and listen to `FlowDocumentScrollViewer.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` will get text selection and add text behavior at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The control handles the event internally.

If you register the event handler programmatically like this, your `doc_MouseLeftButtonUp` event handler should get invoked (note that last `handledEventsToo` parameter):

```
doc.AddHandler(ContentElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, 
    (MouseButtonEventHandler)doc_MouseLeftButtonUp, true);
```

Note that you may also have to take care of the `MouseLeftButtonUp` that is raised by the control itself.

Comment: No, without `e.Handled=true` in `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `doc_MouseLeftButtonUp` will not fire even register with `handledEventsToo=true`.

Comment: So keep `e.Handler = true`? I didn't say that you should remove it.